# Finding alphanumeric in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have character vector in russian language. See the sample vector below -

```
x = "nНозологические единицы  \r\n В20 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде  \r\nинфекционных и паразитарных болезней \r\n В21 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nзлокачественных новообразований \r\n В22 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nдругих уточненных болезней \r\n В78.1 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nдругих состояний \r\n В24 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], неуточненная \r\n Z21 Бессимптомный инфекционный статус, вызванный вирусом иммунодефицита человека"
```

I want to extract these values - **B20, B21, B22, B78.1, B24, Z21**. I am using the code below -

```
gsub("[^0-9A-Za-z///' ]", "", x)
```

But it is returning the wrong result.

```
[1] "n    20     21     22   781      24         Z21       "
```

Comment: do you want all the substring which are in format of ASCII aphanumeric?

Comment: yes, i want all the substring which are in format of ASCII aphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringr`, you can use `str_extract_all` with this regex

```r
x = "nНозологические единицы  \r\n В20 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде  \r\nинфекционных и паразитарных болезней \r\n В21 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nзлокачественных новообразований \r\n В22 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nдругих уточненных болезней \r\n В78.1 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], проявляющаяся в виде \r\nдругих состояний \r\n В24 Болезнь, вызванная вирусом иммунодефицита человека [ВИЧ], неуточненная \r\n Z21 Бессимптомный инфекционный статус, вызванный вирусом иммунодефицита человека"

stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[:alpha:][[:digit:]\\.]+")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "В20"   "В21"   "В22"   "В78.1" "В24"   "Z21"
```

About the regex:

- `[:alpha:]` means any letter character
- `[[:digit:]\\.]` followed by any  numeric or `.` character
- `+` the previous one or more time

Change the regex when what you want to extract changes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using `gregexpr` to return positions and `regmatches` to extract matching portions of text.

```
unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[ВZ][27][[:digit:].]+", x)))
[1] "В20"   "В21"   "В22"   "В78.1" "В24"   "Z21"
```

Note that the "B" is not the standard ascii "B". I copied and pasted one from the vector to get this to work. You can see this using `utfToInt`:

ascii "B":

```
utf8ToInt("B")
[1] 66
```

The "B" in x

```
utf8ToInt("В")
[1] 1042
```